# Qt: Use functors as sender in connect(...)

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and I wonder how to connect a functor to a slot properly.

This is basically what I tried:

```
std::function<void ()> sender_function = std::bind(SenderClass::senderFunction, sender);
...
connect(sender, &sender_function, this, &ThisClass::SomeFunction);
```

However, it does not work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks and best regards,
Alex

**Edit:** 
Use case is the following. I have a set of ~50 parameters fed by sensors in a fixed frequency. To plot the data individually, I have a signal for every parameter which is called when an update arrives. These signals I store in a vector in a structured way, so I don’t need to perform lookups for every parameter (updates can come with 100-1000 Hz).

Now my idea was, that plots can dynamically connect to the parameter signals, by performing a look up once on connection (parameter name -> signal as std::function).

**Edit 2:**
Because there were further questions, here some code examples. I hope this makes it clearer. The signals for parameter updates look like this:

```
signals:
  void DataController::port000(double timestamp, Parameter_t p);
```

Port000 is of course an example, I have 50 more like that, so that every parameter can be individually sent through my program for plotting etc. Next I created a vector of my signals:

```
using PortUpdateFunc = std::function<void (double, Parameter_t)>;

QVector<PortUpdateFunc> _port_update_functions;

_port_update_functions[0] = std::bind(&DataController::port000, this, ph::_1, ph::_2);
```

This allows me to easily just call _port_update_functions[30](stamp, parameter) and it will send the parameter that I linked with that port on its way. This is the sender side. Now on the slot side I have something like this:

```
switch(port_id)
    {
    case 0: QObject::connect(sender, &DataController::port000, this, &SomeSlotFunction); break;
    case 1: QObject::connect(sender, &DataController::port001, this, &SomeSlotFunction); break;
    }
```

While this works perfectly fine, I have to explicitly put all the ports in my switch-case handle. And if I have 50 parameters thats 50 cases with port000 to port049, which is a bit of type work. What I thought of doing was something like this:

```
DataController::PortUpdateFunc port_functor = _port_update_functions[port_id];
QObject::connect(sender, &port_functor, this, &SomeSlotFunction);
```

So I could replace the port000, port001, ... case-handle by just getting the functor from the initial _port_update_functions vector with the appropriate port_id. But Qt doesn't like that idea.

Comment: The second argument in `connect` is used to look up the function pointer as a slot index in the QObject internals. It makes no sense to pass in a functor there.

Comment: The signal has to be a signal, i.e. a member function generated by moc

Comment: The function behind the std::function is a signal. But Qt probably doesn’t recognise it as such. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question with a suitable use case that demonstrates more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I provided my use case as edit! Hope you understand it, currently on my phone so no code example possible.

Comment: Do all the signals have the same signature?  When connecting dynamically do you always connect to the same set of slots/receivers.  Sorry, but there are a *lot* of details missing from this question.

Comment: I put in some code example, maybe this is clearer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 001, 002 variable/method names, most likely you are doing something wrong. Also, it is better that a Plot class does not know about specific ports and does not deal with the selection and connection / disconnection of signals.

For the example you wrote, you can easily use universal signals' signature like this:

`void DataController::portData(int number, double timestamp, Parameter_t p);`

or just

`void DataController::portData(QVariant var);`

or use interface:

```
struct IParam
{
    ...
    virtual QVector<QPointF> toVector() const = 0;
}

struct ConcreteParamName : public IParam
{
    double timestamp; 
    Parameter_t p;
    ...

    QVector<QPointF> toVector() const override
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then `emit portData(1, timestamp, p);`

or `emit portData(QVariant::fromValue(param));`

or

```
emit portData(sharedPointerToParam);
...

void SomeController::portDataSlot(QSharedPointer<IParam> param) 
{
    // decide what to draw here:
    if(thePortNeedToDraw)
    {
        QVector<QPointF> curve = param->toVector();

        plot->drawCurve(curve);
    }
}

// or decide what to receive here:
void SomeController::switchSender(int number, bool enabled)
{
    // without boilerplate switch-case
    if(enabled)
    {
        QObject::connect(senders[number], &DataController::portData, this, &SomeController::portDataSlot);
    }
    else
    {
        QObject::disconnect(senders[number], &DataController::portData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm jeah, I think I get it! Instead of having one instance but multiple functions (port000 and so on), I could have multiple instances but connect to the same function. That sounds so much smarter that I feel really stupid of not having thought about it beforehand now :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The signal argument is either a string or a `PointerToMemberFunction`. Functors can only be used as target. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5.

Comment: The std::function is bound to a member function. I understand that there is no guarantee, which is why Qt refuses to take it. But there is no other solution to this?

Comment: There would have to be code implementing "if the functor is called, call these slots". That's what moc generates for signals, but there is no way to generate it for the functor.